# having trouble SUM PER ROW

Tags: java

Im having trouble on my code, I want to print it ROW by Row but I ended up adding all those numbers-

Should look like this --> sum of row 0 is ""
                          sum of row 1 is ""
                          sum of row 2 is ""

```
public class NewClass
{
          public static void main( String[] arg )
          {
           int[][] data = 
            { { 1, 2},
              { 2, 2},
              { 1, 2, 4, 5},
              { 2, 2, 4,},
              { 1, 1, 4, 5 },
              { 2, 1}};

               int sum = 0;

               for ( int row=0; row < data.length; row++)
                 for ( int col=0; col < data[row].length; col++)
                   sum = sum + data[row][col];

                System.out.println( sum );
              }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the outer loop to include the initialization of the sum variable and the printing:

```
for ( int row=0; row < data.length; row++) {
     int sum = 0;
     for ( int col=0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          sum += data[row][col];
     }
     System.out.println("sum of row " + row + " is " + sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move sum inside first loop as well as print also.

```
 for ( int row=0; row < data.length; row++)
        {
           int sum = 0;
          for ( int col=0; col < data[row].length; col++)
          {
           sum = sum + data[row][col];
          }
          System.out.println( sum );
        }
```

Comment: @ChrisValenzuela.. Why use CAPS Lock?

Comment: @ChrisValenzuela: Good luck. Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Have two variables and accumulate it.

```
int totalSum = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    int rowSum = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
        rowSum = rowSum + data[row][col];
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of " + (row + 1) + " is " + rowSum);
    totalSum += rowSum;
}
System.out.println("TotalSum " + totalSum);
```